# Checkout remote master branch

Tags: git

I'm trying to checkout a colleague's forked repo. I added their fork as a remote, but all their changes are on the master branch.

How do I checkout their master branch as a feature branch in my local repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git fetch theirremote` if you haven't done so already

`git checkout theirremote/master`

`git checkout -b theirfeature`

This could be done in one `git checkout -b` I guess somehow, or one `git branch` and one simple `git checkout` somehow, but that way is easier to remember without looking up manuals.